# VB.NET won't compile because of underscore

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been running the same project on the same computer for months now in VS2010.

There have been no code changes to the class that contains the following code:

```
Private Event ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Implements STI.Shared.UI.IEditField.ValueChanged
```

Recently, when I compile, I get an error that my class must implement event ValueChanged.[image]

When I remove the underscore and bring the Implements piece to the same line, it compiles.

If I then undo checkout and revert it back to what the code was before, it compiles.

It's just very strange behavior and I'm wondering if anyone out there has experienced something like this.

Comment: Has something changed in either STI.Shared.UI.IRadio or STI.Shared.UI.IEditField?

Comment: And why did you whiteout random areas in the screenshot??  It makes it look like the error is that some of the classnames are trivially spelled wrong.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me, impossible to repro.  Note the wrong interface name in the error message, "STI" is missing.  Pretty strange artifacts in the screen shot as well, only a lower case i is visible, should be uppercase I for STI.  Not so sure what's up with that, have you altered the screenshot?  Reboot first, post to connect.microsoft.com second.

Comment: What is the error for the `Implements` statement? The one you have outlined in the Error List is just a symptom of the error you highlight in the Editor.

Comment: Can an Event implement an interface?  Doesn't the Implements statement need to be *before* your event declaration?

Comment: Ok, so I got this error consistently last week as my deadlines loomed. However, this week it has not caused an issue at all. (figures).  I think it's along the lines of Hans comment; just one of those hidden gremlins between VS2010 and my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error, but only with a slight technicallity:

```
Public Interface ITest

    'Note here i have specified System.EventArgs
    Event ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  

End Interface

Public Class TestFail
    Implements ITest

    'And here I have only specified EventArgs, which is fine...
    Private Event ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Implements ITest.ValueChanged

End Class

'Unless you declare another class called EventArgs in the same namespace...
Public Class EventArgs

End Class


Public Class TestWin
    Implements ITest

    'It should work if you just prefix the EventArgs with System though, like so:
    Private Event ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Implements ITest.ValueChanged

End Class
```

And this is the errors you will get from it:

[image: Error List]

Comment: The project has a similar setup to this so I bet it's along these lines.  Kudos for figuring out a way to even produce the error.  The event declaration in the Interface looks like this:  Event ValueChanged As EventHandler                    So it could be along the same lines.  I no longer get the error now (which I'm happy about...but also frustrated I don't know what caused it).  I'm sure it'll show up again when my next deadline date approaches :P

Comment: Haha, it's always at deadlines these things happen. The Compilers knows!  The `As EventHandler` part is just telling it to be of the form `Event xxx(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs)`.  I have updated my answer with a work around too :)

Comment: It was me,@Pondidum; but it wasn't a downvote.  This problem has continuously occurred for me in the past year and I went to SO to search for an answer.  When I found this post with an accepted answer, I was delighted.  Then I saw that the question was posted by _ME_ and the answer wasn't exactly an answer.  Well, it wasn't a solution to my problem.  However, my OP doesn't ask "how do you solve this?".  It only asks if you experienced something like it.  So I am restoring your post as the answer and will just muddle over this till I forget I asked the question and return to this post nxt year.

Comment: @ray023: ah, thats fair enough.  Good luck finding the cause :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the underscore in that situation. Having the underscore in this case isn't even valid syntax. That does seem a bit strange. Seems like Implements would be considered an argument to the CLASS statement, but it's not. It's considered a context sensitive statement all it's own.

Comment: I know.  FTR, this particular project was not coded by me or anyone on our team.  It seems obvious to remove the underscore but sometimes even the most obvious and seemingly harmless changes can have adverse affects.   I would remove it and check-in but I'm the only one on the team getting the error.